# Setting volume to 0 of sound file in phonegap media plugin throws nullpointer exception?

Tags: android, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap media plug in in my app for background music.
For that I am using five different sound files for different views.

Problem comes when i set the volume of media files.

### My Code:

```
var my_media = '';
var my_game = '';
var my_popup = '';
var my_button = '';

my_media = new Media(login_audio, onSuccess, onError, onStatus);
my_game = new Media(inline_audio, onSuccess, onError, onStatusGame);
my_popup = new Media(popUp_audio, onSuccess, onError);
my_button = new Media(touch_audio, onSuccess, onError);
```

After declaring if i set volume it throws NullPointer exception :

```
    my_media.setVolume('0.0');  
    my_game.setVolume('0.0');
    my_button.setVolume('0.0');     
    my_popup.setVolume('0.0');
```

But if i play sound first and then set its volume the it works perfect.

Am i doing something wrong.
Please help!

Logcat:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that at least one of your "Media" objects didn't get created for some reason. Check your logcat (posting it would help too).

You should check if your Media aren't "null" before using them anyway.

Comment: Logcat is not showing any error while creating object .

Comment: It's supposed to show why your application crashes while it runs. Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: I added logcat image . please check .